# Android Camera Intent not working in OnePlus devices

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

I was trying to use the native camera app that comes pre-installed in Android devices to capture the images for my app. For this I've been using this code:

A function is called when the user taps on button

```
take_img_btn.setOnClickListener {
    dispatchTakePictureIntent()
}
```

That function is supposed to do this:

```
    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                    null
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SS",Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "FNL_${timeStamp}_",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
            currentPhotoName = name
        }
    }
```

And the FileProvider is configured in the Manifest like so

```
<application>
   ...
   <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
```

I am also asking for Camera feature in Manifest

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

When I run this app on my android device (Realme 6 Pro) and tap the button then:

> 1. The app opens the native camera app
> 2. I can capture the image
> 3. The image is saved to the location where it was specified

But when this same app is deployed on OnePlus devices (in our case OnePlus Nord) and tap the button then nothing happens. It feels like the button is not programmed.

This code is taken from here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

It would be really helpful if someone help.

Comment: Try removing the `resolveActivity()` bit, and instead wrap the `startActivityForResult()` call in a `try`/`catch`. `resolveActivity()` may require [package visibility adjustments on Android 11+](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am not good at explaining**

As [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) suggested, here is what I did.

I basically avoided the usage of `resolveActivity()` and did it in my own style instead of just copy-paste from **Official Google Documentation**

Here is my final call for camera app:

```
    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        val photoFile: File? = try {
            createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace()
            null
        }

        if (photoFile != null){
            val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                photoFile
            )
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        }
    }


    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SS",Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "FNL_${timeStamp}_",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
            currentPhotoName = name
        }
    }
```

At last, thank you very much [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)

Answer (score 3):

in higher version devices like Oneplus nord with android 11 or 12 the camera intent not working i added this code it is worked for me

Add this line in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

and also add your other permission required for camera